# Size JointJS Rect shape based on text?

Tags: jointjs

Usually, when we create a Rect shape in JointJS, we specify a size.

```
var cell = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
  size: size,
  attrs: {
    text: {
      text: text
    }
  }
});
graph.addCell(cell);
```

Is there a way to not provide a `size` property, but have the shape take on the dimensions required to fit the text?

I am aware of `joint.util.breaktext`, but I do not wish to break text in this case.